# I can't add my list to lazycolumn. how can i add

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I'm adding my notes in "items" but I'm getting this error. I couldn't find the reason, can you help?

```
@Composable
fun NotesList() {
    val notesList = remember { mutableStateListOf<Note>() }
    LazyColumn {
        items(notesList) {note->
            NoteCard(note.title, note.content,note.color,note.liked)
        }
    }
}
```

When I hover the cursor over noteList I get the following error.

Type mismatch.
Required:Int
Found:SnapshotStateList

I was hoping it would work by adding my list to items but it didn't.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Adding this import should fix that:

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.items
```

This is because the `fun items(count: Int)` function is a member function of `LazyListScope` but the `fun <T> LazyListScope.items(items: List<T>)` is an extension function of `LazyListScope`. Therefore, you don't need any import to use the first one, but you need that import to use the second one. If you (or Android studio) doesn't add the import, the one with `count` is automatically used and it doesn't work when you pass list instead.

Comment: Error fixed, thank you very much.

Comment: damn, i thought i was going crazy, thanks for the solution